# Spring Cloud Config Git Backend with a monorepo strategy

Tags: git, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config, monorepo

How do I configure Spring Cloud Config with a Git backend following a monorepo strategy? Say, my repo name is `mono-repo`, and my application config lies in a feature branch `feature/cloud-application-config`, and the configurations are in a directory named `application-config`, how do I configure the Config Server to clone this repository and get config from this feature branch?

Comment: Do you need to get configuration for Spring Cloud Config Server for itself as well from your monorepo ? or just provide configuration for other applications?

Comment: Just for the other services; along with a common `application.yml` file. I've worked it out and added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the property `spring.cloud.config.label=feature(_)cloud-application-config` (which specifies the branch) in both the config server and its clients did the trick. But I also had to modify `spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths` to :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ...
          searchPaths:
            - application-config
            - "application-config/{application}"

      label: feature(_)cloud-application-config
```

I had to add both paths to *searchPaths* because otherwise, it would not get the properties from the common `application-<profile>.yml` files, or from the directories which have the application name.

[Spring Cloud Config Server - Git Backend](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_git_backend)